# Decomposition of bilinear function into symmetric and skew-symmetric in $\mathbb{k}$ with $\operatorname{char}\mathbb{k}=2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that if $\varphi:V\times V\to \mathbb{k}$ with $\operatorname{char}\mathbb{k}\neq 2$ is bilinear function  then $\varphi=a+b$, where $a, b$ are symmetric and skew symmetric bilinear functions.

It can be done in the following way: $$\varphi(x,y)=\dfrac{\varphi(x,y)+\varphi(y,x)}{2}+\dfrac{\varphi(x,y)-\varphi(y,x)}{2}=a(x,y)+b(x,y).$$

But is this claim true if $\operatorname{char}\mathbb{k}=2$? I guess not because in this field I cannot divide by $2$.

Let's do it rigorously. Suppose we can write $\varphi(x,y)=a(x,y)+b(x,y)$ where $a(x,y), b(x,y)$ are symmetric and skew-symmetric functions, respectively.

Then one can show that: $\varphi(x,y)=-\varphi(y,x)$ and $\varphi(x,y)=\varphi(y,x)$ which means that $\varphi$ is simultaneously symmetric and skew-symmetric. But where is the contradiction?

Would be very thankful for any comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in such a field, the symmetric forms and the skew forms are the same because $-k = k$. Hence if $b(x,y) = -b(y,x)$ then in fact $b(x,y) = b(y,x)$ and
so $b$ is symmetric.

So to answer the question, any non symmetric bilinear form cannot be represented as the sum of a symmetric form and skew form.

For example, $\phi(x,y) = x_1 y_2$. We see that $\phi(e_1,e_2) = 1$ but
$\phi(e_2,e_1) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But what is the essence of this example?

Comment: You cannot write a bilinear form with the desired decomposition. If the example $\phi$ was equal to the sum of a symmetric form and skew form, then it would be symmetric which $\phi$ is not, hence such a decomposition is impossible in general.

Comment: Ohh yeah. You just provided an example of form which is not symmetric. Your answer is very clear! Thanks a lot for your permanent help! +1

Comment: I always find it a bit strange that characteristic 2 fields are a bit unusual and go against our intuition.